# logging out session across cross domain through jsp

Tags: java, jsp, cross-domain

I have a application in which the user who logs in is actually belongs to other application.Now I want to logout session of that user by hitting the other application page through the help pf ajax request making a call to my application. And that application should make a call to other application present in other server and logout the session of the user.

In short this is a cross domain request.Please help me in out this.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Let me know if the following is correct...The user logs in to the 1st application in a browser.  Then, the user logs into the 2nd application in the same browser and they get in automatically because they're already logged into the 1st application.  Then, once they've gone into the 2nd application, you want the session to be destroyed for the 1st application.  Am I off on what I've stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Call the logout functionality of your application to which the user has logged on using ajax.